# SQL Rank and Order

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I'm working with a dataset in which I'm looking to get the #1 seller for each class_rk sold with a driver SKU, followed by #2 seller in each class_rk, etc. The Class_rk (which is associated with the sold_sku) has already been identified in previous query. Here is the dataset:

```
 driver_sku sold_sku    class_rk    sold_units
 555        432           1         20
 555        235           2         17
 555        322           2         15
 555        253           1         14
 555        152           3         13
 555        732           1          9
 555        913           3          6
```

The output I'd be looking for:

```
 driver_sku sold_sku    class_rk    sold_units
 555        432           1         20
 555        235           2         17
 555        152           3         13
 555        253           1         14
 555        322           2         15
 555        913           3          6
 555        732           1          9
```

Here is the code I've tried thus far:

```
 select driver_sku, sold_sku, class_rk, sold_count,
 row_number() over(partition by driver_item_id order by class_rk, sold_count  desc) as rank from data_table;
```

Comment: Which dbms? (Not all products support this functionality.)

Comment: using hive in hadoop

Comment: @GordonLinoff - the class_rk is of the sold_sku

Comment: Why does the numbering start over again on the fourth row?

Comment: I'm not following the ordering logic here...

Comment: @Siyual - i basically just want the top sold_sku in each class_rk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how you describe the problem, you seem to want to partition by `class_rk`:

```
select driver_sku, sold_sku, class_rk, sold_count,
       row_number() over(partition by driver_item_id, class_rk
                         order by sold_count desc
                        ) as rank
from data_table;
```

However, this does not conform to the desired results.

EDIT:

Based on how you describe the problem, you seem to want to partition by `class_rk` and change the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from (select driver_sku, sold_sku, class_rk, sold_count,
             row_number() over (partition by driver_item_id, class_rk
                                order by sold_count desc
                               ) as rank
      from data_table
     ) t
order by rank, class_rk
```

If you actually want to enumerate them:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by driver_sku, rank
                          order by sold_count desc) as newcol
from (select driver_sku, sold_sku, class_rk, sold_count,
             row_number() over (partition by driver_item_id, class_rk
                                order by sold_count desc
                               ) as rank
      from data_table
     ) t
order by rank, class_rk
```

Comment: It does not give top sold_sku for each class_rk, for example top sold_sku in class_rk  #1, then top sold_sku in class_rk #2, etc

Comment: @jKraut . . . That comment helps clarify the problem.  You want to partition by the *rank*.  I think I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you just want one record for each class_rk. I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT driver_sku, sold_sku, class_rk, max(sold_count)
FROM <TABLE>
GROUP BY driver_sku, class_rk
ORDER_BY class_rk
```

However if you want the ordering to be like in your question, I think you'd have to do something like this:

```
with ranked as (
    SELECT driver_sku, sold_sku, class_rk, sold_count,
        row_number() over(partition by driver_sku, class_rk order by sold_count desc) as rank
    FROM <TABLE>    
)

SELECT driver_sku, sold_sku, class_rk, sold_count
FROM ranked
GROUP BY driver_sku, rank
ORDER BY class_rk
```